# C# Sockets Sending Serialized Data

Tags: c#, sockets, serialization, tcp

I am having trouble sending serialized data over a TCP/IP socket connection.

My send function looks like this:

```
public void SendData(NetworkConnection connection, ReplicableObject ro) {
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            bf.Serialize(ms, ro);

            ms.WriteTo(connection.TcpStream);
            connection.TcpStream.Flush();

            ms.Close();
        }
```

I'm aware that currently TcpStream.Flush() doesn't do anything. That's not my issue, anyway.

On the receiving (client) end, the reader looks like this:

```
byte[] readBuffer = new byte[8192];
            worldMapStream = worldMapConnection.GetStream();
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            IsConnectedToWorldMap = true;
            while (true) {
                try {
                    do {
                        int bytes = worldMapStream.Read(readBuffer, 0, readBuffer.Length);
                        ms.Write(readBuffer, 0, bytes);
                    }
                    while (worldMapStream.DataAvailable);

                    try {
                        ReplicableObject ro = (ReplicableObject) bf.Deserialize(ms);
                        ro = ro;
                    }
                    catch (Exception e) {
                        e = e;
                    }
                }
```

The strange ro = ro and e = e lines are just there so I can add a breakpoint.

My problem is this: The read always fails. I get an exception caught, and the message explains that the end of the stream was reached before parsing was completed. Now, I understand that the data might not all arrive in one chunk, but I haven't cleared the memory stream on catching an exception, so the next chunk should just add the remaining data onto the end of it, right? But this doesn't work, apparently.

So, what am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance. :)

P.S. I understand that WCF is the better alternative to this; but unfortunately I can't use that in this project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here we go:

```
while (worldMapStream.DataAvailable);
```

Should be:

```
while(bytes>0);
```

Which also means moving `bytes` outside the loop.

`DataAvailable` just means "right now, at the NIC". It doesn't tell you whether more is coming or not. Also, you should ony *Write* when `bytes>0` too; to be honest a `while` loop is easier here :)

Then; after filling `ms` set ms.Position = 0 to rewind te stream.

Comment: I'm sorry, I must misunderstand... Surely that loop will never be exited then? As every time the tcpstream is read from bytes will be greater than 0; leading it to go back to the start of the loop and read again?

Comment: @Motig it'll return <= 0 when closed. Also, there's a second bug - see edit

Comment: @Motig - also, I *dont* think WCF would be better here; but I can suggest a better serializer than BinaryFormatter if you like :)

Comment: Hi again, sorry about the belated reply. Surely setting ms.Position = 0 would write the new data infront of the existing data? A bit like writing the word 'Hello' at first with 'He' and then resetting to the start to write 'llo'... Resulting in 'lloHe'?

Comment: Also, NetworkStream.Read() is a blocking command, no? So how can it 'return' anything other than a positive value?

Comment: @Motig - you rewind before deserializing - not after every Write

Comment: @Motig it is only blocking *while the stream is open*; your client closes the stream, so it will return <= 0 when EOF. If your intention is to send multiple messages on the same stream, you will need something like a length-prefix. Or; use a serializer that supports that type of usage out of the box (I.e. Knows how to read the exact amount of data from a network stream without ever over-reading)